# Why can't I define properties or functions on prototype via Object.defineProperties()?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I want to set multiple properties on the prototype of my object at once, since Object.defineProperties() takes an object(and prototype is an object) and descriptors, and my object obj has already a prototype as it comes with every object,i am trying to modify the prototype of my object as follows

```
var obj = document.createElement(tn);

obj.prototype = Object.defineProperties(obj.prototype,{
    getName:{
        value:function(){
            alert("I have the tag"+this.tagName);
        },
        configurable:true
        }
    });
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Object.defineProperties called on non-object
```

why?

Comment: A "div" Node for example inherits from `HTMLDivElement`. Your `obj` has no prototype itself. What are you trying to do here...?

Comment: But I am creating an object which is of type Element,won't it carry the same thing as Element.prototype?If not how do I refer to it?

Comment: I think you might be misusing `prototye` here, you don't need to extend anything, you can create your own object and a function that takes `obj` as parameter.

Comment: point your object's prototype to Element.prototype.

Comment: BTW your usage of the method is messed up. refer the docs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, `obj.prototype` is undefined.

You point it to some other object, properties will be added to it.

JS has a prototype based inheritance model where an object inherits from another object, if it doesn't have a property or a method, it looks to its prototype object which is just another object with property and methods which again might have its own prototype object.

You are getting the error `Object.defineProperties called on non-object` simply because `obj.prototype` is not an object and is undefined.

set it to window or an empty `{}`, it should work for you.